# Why is ArcMap reverting 4-band raster settings?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, symbology

ArcMap keeps redrawing my 4 band false colour image in standard 3 colour bands.  As you can see below I have my 4 band data set to auto display as (4,1,2 - infrared, red, green).  When I bring in an image layer it displays as it should and the layer properties clearly show my settings are working.

If however, I pan around and zoom in the image reverts to a 3 band image - the image difference is shown in the attached image.  When I go back into image properties it shows that ArcMap has automatically changed my bands to (1,2,3 - R,G,B) - even though my customization menu still shows my desired settings as (4,1,2 - iR, R, G).

Any idea why ArcMap is doing this?

I[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reference to ArcGIS help you can change the default bands combination, but you need to specify it in the 3 band data source:

> You can specify a different set of defaults, mapping bands to R,G,B display values for datasets with three bands and those with four or more bands. For example, depending on the data you use most often, you may specify that bands 3,2,1 be used for the R,G,B rather than 1,2,3. Or if you prefer to see a particular band combination when using data with more than 3 bands, you could specify 6,4,3 or 4,3,2 for the default R,G,B combination.

You can check [Setting the default bands to display multiband rasters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/setting-the-default-bands-to-display-multiband-rasters.htm)